# Android UI Freezes on public servers

Tags: android, server, freeze

Good day.Im developing android apps,i have more then one year development experience and here is how it go.First we tried all files to do on local server(we bough a PC and all php files and servers was there) and started development there.I was using android development official guide to connect to server within asynctask and without .get() method not to hold ui thread and all huge works were done in worker thread,not on ui.In local server everything was perfect and fine,app will never hang or freeze at all!Yesterday we changed all server constants to public and for my big surprise the app started to freeze as soon as it will connect to server and get response from it.It freezes(hangs) for couple seconds causing ANR and later after long period it become responsive.I have google all day long but there wasn't even a little hint to my surprised issue.My question is the next.Will the android freeze if server would not work fast(send and receive data),or will not be able to asynchronous send the response to all clients at one time?If server have nothing to do with ui freeze,ill post my project codes,though there is must not be any issue with..Thank you very much,please help as the company complaining about my not professional work:(but i bet that its the server issue!

Comment: Since you are doing network operations on asynctask and worker threads, your app should not freeze. Even if server is slow, response you receive will be delayed, app wont freeze since it runs in background. Check your code where you are doing network operations.

Comment: i did check my codes 10 times yesterday,even on pause of my activity i destroyed asynctask,for it not to work if the activity have been left,its really not logical,because ill give the simplest example now.i have profile view in app,inside the profile i receive 10 string!nothing too high,no images,no sounds nothing!just simple strings,the damned app keeps freezing!:(oh and i have a service which works all the time and within 5 seconds delay it connects to server(for notification purpose) and 2 more asyntask within inside app which doing same in-app notification purpose,might it be the cause?

Comment: oh and plus i use google maps,might google maps freeze the app too?the google maps are put on the child of tabhost of android!

Comment: i just though about everything which is possible and coming to decision that app must not freeze if it wasn't freezing on local,it must not freeze on public am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Finally doing researches and trying every possible situation i came up to the solution.Guys taking example from my own mistakes(mainly mistake of my colleague:)) never do the next!If you want some code to be executed every 5 seconds NEVER EVER use Thread for that!as for some code to be run every for example 5 seconds you use `Thread.sleep(//some seconds)` and it will actually block the ui thread if you call this method not inside asynctask so avoid it.In my case there was a thread inside android default navigation drawer which was executing some asynctask every 5 seconds to check for any new incoming messages which was causing actually app to freeze(though it strange as on local server it will never happen,i guess because of the response delay,in local it was very fast so we did not notice any freeze) and you always do use ScheduledExecutorService for that.(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) Thanks everyone for help!